# I want to show video thumbnail from online video?

Tags: android

```
Bitmap bm ;  
ThumbnailUtils tu = new ThumbnailUtils();  
bm = tu.createVideoThumbnail("http://*****.mp4",Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

but return is **null**